# Puppeteer: Open headless instance non-headless

Tags: webautomation, puppeteer

was wondering if it is possible to open a previously headless instance non-headless and to continue where you stopped. I have tried to just change headless to false during the process, however, it didnt work.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, the processes started are fundamentally different, so you cannot switch between them at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, are there any alternatives though?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is saving all the cookies, local storage and reloading everything in a new non-headless instances, but there's no guarantee at all it's gonna produce the same "state" of the page. However, it seems a bit strange what you want do do, what is your use case?

Comment: A good usercase is when you simply want to hide/show the chrome window in case there is a prompt or google recaptcha etc.

Comment: Right, I want to automate a checkout and in case there is something unexpected it should show the browser.